# welcome message in ConversationUpdate for messenger

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

Using ConversationUpdate I show a welcome message.
I have tested the code in bot framework emulator where it works fine.

I tried it in facebook messenger and got no response.

**Question**: Is it supported in messenger?

```
IConversationUpdateActivity update = message as IConversationUpdateActivity;

var client = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(update.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
if (update.MembersAdded != null)
{
    foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
    {
        if (newMember.Id != update.Recipient.Id)
        {
            var reply = ((Activity)update).CreateReply($"Hello "+newMember.Name);

            client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
       }
   }
}
```

Specifically the bot must show the welcome message each time a member starts a conversation. Also I added the code:

```
newMember.Id != update.Recipient.Id
```

because the message was showing up twice in emulator.

The rest are quite simple and expected to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConversationUpdate` event isn't supported in the Facebook Messenger channel. Facebook Messenger doesn't broadcast an event by default when the users opens a chat. There are two options to achieve similar behaviour:

1. Use the [Get Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button) property to track new conversations. I wrote a blogpost about [how to catch this specific event in BotBuilder V3](https://imick.nl/how-to-handle-referrals-optins-postbacks-on-facebook-using-microsoft-bot-framework/), you can do something similar for BotBuilder V4.
2. Respond with your welcome message after the first message interaction of the user.